# $\lim_{t\to \infty}k_1(t)=\lim_{\lambda \to 0}\lambda \widehat{k_1}(\lambda)$?

Tags: integration, physics, laplace-transform, bessel-functions

Can we conclude that
$$\displaystyle \lim_{t\to \infty}k_1(t)=\lim_{\lambda \to 0}\lambda \widehat{k_1}(\lambda)?$$
Here $\widehat{k_1}$ is the Laplace transform of a function $k_1:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ nonnegative, left-continuous, nonincreasing. It is a question that appear while I have reading the book of Jan Prüss (Evolutionary integral equations and applications, pg. 93), exist more assumptions about $k_1$. I am trying use integration by parts, but i cant answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. $\lambda \hat {k_1}(\lambda) =\lambda \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t } k_1(t)dt=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-s} k_1(\frac s {\lambda}) ds$. We can aply Monotone Convergence Theorem to conclude that $\lambda \hat {k_1}(\lambda) \to k_1(\infty)$ as $ \lambda$ decreases to $0$.

Comment: very, very good. Thanks!!